# Is using multiple Sql connection in a button click in c# in asp.net is efficient?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

```
public void buttonclick(object sender,eventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con0 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BUM"].ConnectionString);
    con0.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd0 = new SqlCommand("", con0);
    con0.Close();

    SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BUM"].ConnectionString);
    con1.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("book_master_insert", con1);
    cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    SqlParameter customer_id = new SqlParameter("@customer_id", cust_id);
    SqlParameter booking_from = new SqlParameter("@booking_from", ddlfrom.SelectedItem.Text);
    SqlParameter booking_destination = new SqlParameter("@booking_destination", ddlto.SelectedItem.Text);
    SqlParameter load_type = new SqlParameter("@load_type", ddlLoadtype.SelectedItem.Text);
    SqlParameter no_of_containers = new SqlParameter("@no_of_containers", txt_no_of_container.Text);
    SqlParameter booking_pickupdate = new SqlParameter("@booking_pickupdate", txt_date.Text);
    SqlParameter booking_pickuptime = new SqlParameter("@booking_pickuptime", txt_time.Text);
    SqlParameter booking_createdate = new SqlParameter("@booking_createdate", localDate);

    cmd3.Parameters.Add(customer_id);
    cmd3.Parameters.Add(booking_createdate);
    cmd3.Parameters.Add(booking_from);
    cmd3.Parameters.Add(booking_destination);
    cmd3.Parameters.Add(load_type);
    cmd3.Parameters.Add(no_of_containers);
    cmd3.Parameters.Add(booking_pickupdate);
    cmd3.Parameters.Add(booking_pickuptime);

    cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con1.Close();

    SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BUM"].ConnectionString);
    con2.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select  booking_ID from booking_master where customer_id='"+cust_id+"' and booking_from='" + ddlfrom.SelectedItem.Text + "'and booking_destination='" + ddlto.SelectedItem.Text + "' and load_type='" + ddlLoadtype.SelectedValue + "' and no_of_containers='" + txt_no_of_container.Text + "' and CAST (booking_pickupdate as date) ='" + txt_date.Text + "' and booking_pickuptime='" + txt_time.Text + "';", con2);

    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        booking_ID = rdr["booking_ID"].ToString();
    }

    con2.Close();
}
```

Comment: If you are connecting to the same server and the same database, you don't need to close the connection after first query. Leave it open. Change the SqlCommand and send the query again. If all queries are finish, then you can close the connection.

Comment: You don't do the `SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select  booking_ID ....` in production? https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection SqlInjection is very dangerous

Answer (score 0):

Because con0, con1, and con2 are the same, you can write it like this, and please make cmd2 like cmd3, using parameterized query:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("...Connection String..."))
{
  conn.Open();
  using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
  {
    cmd.Connection = conn;

    // Query1
    cmd.CommandText = "...Query1...";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // Query2
    cmd.CommandText = "...Query2...";
    cmd.ExecuteReader();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Talking about efficiency first what are you trying to do?

1. System.Data.SqlClient ( ADO.Net ) re-use [connection pooling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx) if it detects new connection is same with the first connection made base on it connectionstring.
2. Calling multiple SqlConnection doesn't matter as long as you close and dispose it after use. Much better if you wrap it with `using() {}` statement, but keep in mind that it depend on what you are trying to do or what you requirement is. Open/Close of connection is much cheaper than hold open connection for long time. If you can re-use connection do it like what @x... answers.
3. It is nothing to do with efficiency but you should **AVOID** appending user input value in you SQL query. This lead to SQL injection and exploitation like what @mar_s said. Alternatively you can use `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "Bob");` for your safety.

**Note** : I haven't tested the code :

```
public void buttonclick(object sender,eventArgs e)
{
    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BUM"].ConnectionString;

    using(SqlConnection con0 = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        con0.Open();
        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("book_master_insert", con0))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;              
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customer_id", cust_id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@booking_from", ddlfrom.SelectedItem.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@booking_destination", ddlto.SelectedItem.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@load_type", ddlLoadtype.SelectedItem.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@no_of_containers", txt_no_of_container.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@booking_pickupdate", txt_date.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@booking_pickuptime", txt_time.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@booking_createdate", localDate);              
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // This is a BAD idea and you should replace this using parametrized queries
            using(SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select booking_ID from booking_master where customer_id='"+cust_id+"' and booking_from='" + ddlfrom.SelectedItem.Text + "'and booking_destination='" + ddlto.SelectedItem.Text + "' and load_type='" + ddlLoadtype.SelectedValue + "' and no_of_containers='" + txt_no_of_container.Text + "' and CAST (booking_pickupdate as date) ='" + txt_date.Text + "' and booking_pickuptime='" + txt_time.Text + "';", con2))
            {       
                using(SqlDataReader rdr = cmd2.ExecuteReader())
                {       
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        booking_ID = rdr["booking_ID"].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```